# Let $M$ be a left $R-module$. Prove that the following are equivalent:

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, ring-homomorphism

Let $M$ be a left $R-module$. Prove that the following are equivalent:

(a) M is simple;

(b) Every non zero homomorphism $M \to N$ is a monomorphism;

I know that a module $M$ is simple if and only if every cyclic submodule generated by a non-zero element of $M$ equals $M$.I assume (a) but i couldnt go longer. Please some hint.

Edit: (a)->(b): If $M$ is simple then $M$'s only submodules are ${0}$ and $M$. Let $M$ be simple and $\phi:M\to N$ be a non zero homomorphism. $\operatorname{Ker}\phi$ is a submodule of $M$. Then $\operatorname{Ker}\phi=0$ or $\operatorname{Ker}\phi=M$ but it cant be $M$

(b)->(a): Let $N\leq M$ and $\pi:M\to M/N$ be natural homomorphism. Then $\operatorname{Ker}\pi=N$, we know that $\pi$ is monomorphism because of our assumption so $\operatorname{Ker}\pi=\{0\}$. Thus $N=\{0\}$

Comment: Take a nonzero homomorphism $M\to N$. Its kernel is a submodule. Don't know what other hints can be given here.

Comment: I assume (a) and say that has no non-zero submodule. Because of this my homomorphism is zero and then it is a monomorphism am I right?

Comment: $M$ being simple means that its only submodules are $\{0\}$ and $M$. So if $\varphi: M\to N$ is a homomorphism then $Ker(\varphi)$ is either $\{0\}$ or all $M$. But if it is a nonzero homomorphism then the kernel can't be all $M$, so it has to be $\{0\}$.

Comment: I got this. But when I assume (b) I cant go to (a). I said let assume (b) and let (a) is false. But nothing came up

Comment: This direction is a bit more interesting. You assume $(b)$ and have to show $M$ is simple, i.e all its submodules are $\{0\}$ and $M$. So let $N\subseteq M$ be a submodule. Try to look at the projection homomorphism $\pi:M\to M/N$ defined by $\pi(m)=m+N$.

Comment: Thank you very much this helped me.

Comment: @BeratYILDIRIM if you have now solved your question, please write it up in the solution section. This is fine and in fact encouraged.